# Ubuntu partition sizes

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, partitioning

Today I bought a Lenovo G510 Laptop (4GB Ram, 500GB Hard Drive) and need install both Ubuntu and Windows 7. I have some questions regarding this.

- What OS should I install first ?
- What are the partition sizes should I put for swap, root and home ?

Comment: You should install windows first, easier. see : http://superuser.com/questions/415402/partitioning-500-gb-internal-drive-5-partitions-to-dual-windows-and-ubuntu?rq=1

Comment: Take a look: http://lifehacker.com/5403100/dual-boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-in-perfect-harmony

Answer (score 1):

1. Install Windows first. If you install Ubuntu and then Windows, you risk overwriting the boot loader, and the PC would boot straight into Windows as if Ubuntu were not installed (source: personal experience). Ubuntu has much more respect for existing operating systems :P
2. Swap entirely depends on your usage: are you going to need lots of memory (e.g. are you going to work with very large files that would cause you physical 4 GBs to be not enough)? If so, add the correct amount of swap. Ideally you would increase your available RAM, but if you want to stick with 4 GBs and you do **not** plan to do memory-intensive tasks, I would add 2 GBs of swap. Otherwise I would perhaps use 4 GB.
3. Root: how many programs, desktop environments etc. are you planning to install? Anything between 10 GB - 30 GB could work, but once again, that entirely depends on you.
4. Assign all the space that you have left to your /home partition.